# MapFragment in Fragment, cannot fix the errors

Tags: android

I have a problem about MapFragment in Fragment.
In the main_layout.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_slidermenu"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/list_divider"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"       
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"/>
```

The listView is a menu which I use it to change fragment.
And in MainActivity.java, I change Fragment by this function:

```
private void displayView(int _position) 
{
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (_position) 
    {
        case 0:
            fragment = _YourTravelFragment;
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = _SettingFragment;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    if (fragment != null) 
    {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
        _DrawerList.setItemChecked(_position, true);
        _DrawerList.setSelection(_position);
        setTitle(_MenuTitles[_position]);
        _DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(_DrawerList);
    } else 
    {
        Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
    }
}
```

I create two Fragment, YourTravelFragment and SettingFragment.
In fragment_your_travel.xml has a MapFragement.
So, when the first time I start the application, the map loaded normally. After that, I use slider menu to choose "SettingFragment", the SettingFragment loaded normally, and I use slider menu to choose "YourTravelFragment", and the application has some errors, it exited.
This is "YourTravelFragment.java":
    `private GoogleMap _GoogleMap;
    private SupportMapFragment _SupportMapFragment;

```
public YourTravelFragment()
{
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater _inflater, ViewGroup _container, Bundle _savedInstanceState) 
{
    View rootView = _inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_your_travel, _container, false);
    return rootView;
}

@Override
public void onResume() 
{
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() 
{
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() 
{
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onLowMemory() 
{
    super.onLowMemory();
}`
```

Error:

```
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at com.khaihanhdk.journeydiary.YourTravelFragment.onCreateView(YourTravelFragment.java:37)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:829)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1035)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:635)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1399)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:426)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4960)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #5: Duplicate id 0x7f060044, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:296)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:682)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):     ... 18 more
```

This looks like the culprit. `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #5: Duplicate id 0x7f060044, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment`

Comment: 05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #5: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: 05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:710)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:752)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:495)
05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)

Comment: This looks like the culprit. Please post your other XML files: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Binary XML file line #5: Duplicate id 0x7f060044, tag null, or parent id 0x0 with another fragment for com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment 05-12 23:42:19.432: E/AndroidRuntime(9034):

Comment: Looks like you are trying to duplicate your map fragment. You either need to pop it from your fragment stack before trying to recreate it or you need to transition back to your original map fragment (probably).

Comment: So, how to pop it from my fragment stack?

Comment: I understand the error but I cant fix. This is my full code, I hope my problem will be solved. http://www.mediafire.com/download/by1vf13gbt33sdt/JourneyDiary.rar